# How to render an existing JS function inactive

Tags: jquery, function, twitter-bootstrap

we are currently using bootstrap 3 to handle the structure of websites we build and we are also using the CK editor to manage the content located within the CMS.

We have a Ckeditor plugin which enables all JS and CSS to be included within the editor, which is fantastic as all our content is organised nicely.

My issue is, we have the bootstrap carousel loaded up on the client side and whilst its running perfectly within the site it also renders it as a a proper carousel within the CMS, meaning that all content is stacked upon each other.

What im wondering is... how would someone write a function to replace an existing function so that it doesnt stay in its proper form whilst in the CMS ?

Is it a matter of simply creating a function with the same name ? to render this without the actual carousel functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a function with the same name and signature as the offending function  but with an empty body and include it last. It will overwrite the existing function.